# Change focus in Excel to formula bar via keyboard using Excel 2011 in Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2011

I want to ask the same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/205733/how-can-i-change-the-focus-in-excel-to-the-formula-bar-via-the-keyboard) but for Microsoft Excel 2011 in Mac. The issue is that in Excel 2011 for Mac there is no Tools -> Options.