# Excel keyboard shortcut to edit formula in formula bar

Tags: worksheet-function, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-365

When I press <kbd>F2</kbd> in a cell I can edit it inside the cell. However often it's just more convenient to make the edit in the formula bar.

I can switch to formula bar by mouse, just wondering whether there is a keyboard shortcut for that?

when editing in formula bar, highlights are applied there and also cursor blinks there:
[image: when editing in formula bar, highlights are applied there and also cursor blinks there]

Comment: There are some more answers to this question here: https://superuser.com/questions/205733/how-can-i-change-the-focus-in-excel-to-the-formula-bar-via-the-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Excel options menu, turn off the option `Allow editing directly in cells`. Now when you press <kbd>F2</kbd>, you'll always be editing in the Formula bar.

[image]

I don't believe there's a keyboard-based solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to disable editing directly in cells, there's this long workaround:

If the cell is empty, it's easy: Press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Unfortunately, that shortcut only works if the cell is empty. If the cell is not empty, you must first clear the contents. So you could use this key sequence: <kbd>Del</kbd>, then <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

But assuming you want to retain the original formula, you'd have to copy and paste it.

Thus, if the cell is not empty, this key sequence does the job:

1. <kbd>F2</kbd> (modify the cell in place)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (select the formula)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (cut the formula to clipboard)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (jump to formula bar)
5. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (remove equal sign, since it is already on the clipboard)
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste original content)

Note that steps 2-4 can be reduced to a single step: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no way to do this in Excel 365, as discussed [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/shortcut-to-jump-to-formula-bar-in-excel-365/m-p/3441770).

Will update this answer if this feature arrives.

Comment: Which extra information your post contains compared to existing answer?

Comment: I arrived here, tried the accepted answer but it didn't work (in excel 365). So spent another 15 minutes looking for a solution for excel 365 only to discover that there isn't one. Hence wrote this answer to save those 15 minutes for the next person like me.